# move all gallery items on listview simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am struct on a problem. I have make a custom listview, by inflating gallery on listview. But I struct on that, how to move all items simultaneously (left or right) while scrolling gallery, like application zeebox. I have tried a lot but unfortunately didn't get any solution. Any help will be very appreciable and helpful for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about the Gallery Widget?

Comment: @ Mogambo Khush Hua yes, I have inflated galleryview on listview & want to scroll all item simultaneously on listview

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT use Gallery. It's deprecated, you never know when your application will stop functioning. You can use a HorizontalScrollView to implement the gallery functionality. And about the functionality you want to implement, you can get add a scroll listener to it and scroll all other HorizontalScrollView through that.

To get the scroll position: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getScrollX()

To scroll to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html#scrollTo(int, int)

OnScrollChangedListener: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int)

Hope that helps